# Idade negativa em R

Tags: r, lubridate

Tenho uma base de dados que preciso calcular a idade dos membros nela, abaixo uma amostra extraida com o `dput`.

```
base.teste <- c("04/03/73", "10/09/67", "21/12/74", "17/04/76", "25/03/66", 
"11/03/73", "06/08/79")
```

Preciso calcular a idade de todos os membros no final de novembro, 30/11/2017. Transofmrei os dados em datas, pélo `lubridate` e executei o seguinte código:

```
library(lubridate)
idade <- floor(as.numeric(difftime(data.fim.mes, base.teste, units = "days"))/365.25)
```

Porém no resultado acabo obtendo idades negativas:

```
44 -50  42  41 -49  44  38
```

Alguém sabe o por quê ou possui uma forma de calculo melhor?

Comment: Se você reparar, após a transformação de `base.teste` em `Date` (eu usei a fórmula `as.Date`), os anos de 66 e 67 são convertidos para 2066 e 2067, respectivamente.

Comment: Estou usando o `dmy(base.teste)` e o resultado é :`1973-03-04 2067-09-10 1974-12-21 1976-04-17 2066-03-25 1973-03-11 1979-08-06`

Comment: Da mesma forma, o ano de 67 está sendo convertido para 2067, por isso das idades negativas. Adicionei uma resposta utilizando o pacote `chron` que funcionou da forma esperada para o seu banco de teste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução utilizando o pacote `chron`

```
library(chron)
base.teste <- c("04/03/73", "10/09/67", "21/12/74", "17/04/76", "25/03/66", "11/03/73", "06/08/79")
base.teste <- chron(base.teste, format = c(dates = "d/m/y")) 
data.fim.mes <- "30/11/17"
data.fim.mes <- chron(data.fim.mes, format = c(dates = "d/m/y"))

idade <- floor(as.numeric(difftime(data.fim.mes, base.teste, units = "days"))/365.25)
```

resulta em:

```
idade
[1] 44 50 42 41 51 44 38
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui!. Nem tinha reparado nas datas de `2067`